# Python - cannot import name viewkeys

Tags: python

I'm importing a module which inturn imports `six`, but I'm getting this weird error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/praful/Desktop/got/modules/categories/tests.py", line 13, in <module>
    import microdata
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.10-intel/egg/microdata.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/html5lib/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .html5parser import HTMLParser, parse, parseFragment
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 2, in <module>
    from six import with_metaclass, viewkeys, PY3
ImportError: cannot import name viewkeys
```

I'd a look at [six.py](https://github.com/JioCloud/python-six/blob/master/six.py), it has `viewkeys` in it.

Latest `six==1.10.0` is installed.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't name a file in your working directory `six.py` or somesuch? You might try, in your module, doing a plain `import six`, then `print(six)` and see if it's the one you expect.

Comment: I tried it in python shell as well. I tried importing only `from six import viewkeys`, it returns an error.

Comment: I tried reinstalling it, still the same error.

Comment: Are you running a virtualenv? Is it executed using python3 or python2.7?

Comment: Also, had a look at the code in `site-packages`, it's the same code as https://github.com/JioCloud/python-six/blob/master/six.py

Comment: No virtualenv. I'm using python2.7

Comment: I'm able to run it on my companion's system, but not on me.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast are you both working on macs? OSX uses python-six which is an older package that has been replaced by six. Is there any chance of trying it out in a virtual environment?

Comment: Yes. we are working on mac. No. I'm not using virtual env.

Comment: `OSX uses python-six which is an older package that has been replaced by six.` How do I install the current version of six? I did `pip install six`. Do I need to do something different.

Comment: Not really -  that usually works, I'm assuming that python-six is still in your `PYTHONPATH`, I can't really say if this is the issue that you're having at the moment but it's a possibility. Have you tried comparing your and your co-workers `pip freeze` ?

Comment: Yeah...I did had a look at `pip freeze` on both of our systems.. Both has `six==1.10.0` installed. How do I check if `python-six` is in the PYTHONPATH as well or not?

Comment: I restarted the system, just in case... But no luck.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem:

```
> python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import six
>>> import xhtml2pdf.pisa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xhtml2pdf/pisa.py", line 3, in <module>
    from xhtml2pdf.document import pisaDocument
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xhtml2pdf/document.py", line 2, in <module>
    from xhtml2pdf.context import pisaContext
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xhtml2pdf/context.py", line 23, in <module>
    import xhtml2pdf.parser
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/xhtml2pdf/parser.py", line 17, in <module>
    from html5lib import treebuilders, inputstream
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/html5lib/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .html5parser import HTMLParser, parse, parseFragment
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 2, in <module>
    from six import with_metaclass, viewkeys, PY3
ImportError: cannot import name viewkeys
>>> exit()
```

I ran the following steps:

- `sudo -H pip uninstall six`
- `sudo -H pip install six==1.9.0`
- Test: Error persists
- `sudo -H pip uninstall six==1.9.0`
- `sudo -H pip install six==1.10.0`

Test:

```
> python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from six import viewkeys
>>> import xhtml.pisa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named xhtml.pisa
>>> import xhtml2pdf.pisa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "xhtml2pdf/pisa.py", line 3, in <module>
    from xhtml2pdf.document import pisaDocument
  File "xhtml2pdf/document.py", line 2, in <module>
    from xhtml2pdf.context import pisaContext
  File "xhtml2pdf/context.py", line 23, in <module>
    import xhtml2pdf.parser
  File "xhtml2pdf/parser.py", line 17, in <module>
    from html5lib import treebuilders, inputstream
ImportError: cannot import name inputstream
>>> exit()
```

So the viewkeys-error didn't come back.

The problem importing inputstream seems to be a bug in xhtml2pdf:
https://github.com/xhtml2pdf/xhtml2pdf/issues/318

For me this fixed the problem:
`sudo -H pip install html5lib==1.0b8`

So afterall, I don't really know if the last command would have fixed the problem overall, but this way it works for me now:

```
> python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import xhtml2pdf.pisa
>>>
```

Comment: I have the same problem and installing html5lib==1.0b8 gives me the same import error :/

Answer (score 2):

This is what helped me on my MacBook Pro, OS X Yosemite, 10.10.5

1) Check which six version your Python is using

```
import six
print six.__version__

1.4.0
```

2) Find all six Python packages on your system

```
sudo find / -name 'six*'

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/lib/six.py
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/scipy/lib/six.pyc
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.py
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.pyc
```

3) Check the six versions one by one

```
vi /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.py
```

4) When the file opens scroll down to identify the six version

5) Manually remove all packages older then 1.10.0

```
sudo rm /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.py
sudo rm /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/six.pyc
```

6) Install the latest six package (e.g. 1.11.0):

```
sudo pip install --ignore-installed six
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, PIP was not working, so I can't reinstall six.

What I've done is:

Download latest "six" package from here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six

```
cd /tmp
wget [GET LATEST SIX URL]
tar xf six-1.10.0.tar.gz
cd six-1.10.0
python3 setup.py install
```

Now PIP is working in Python 3, if you need it for Python 2 just change "python3" for "python2" in the last command.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem in the production server and fixed it. Run the following command
`sudo pip install --ignore-installed six`